How to show that multiplication by $i$ is the same as a 90 degree linear transformation of the complex plane
Complex numbers can be represented as vectors in the complex plane. A purely real number $x$ can be written as $(x,0)$ and a purely imaginary number $yi$ can be written as $(0,y)$.
Multiplication of a complex number by $i$ (or $(0,1)$ in vector form) results in a rotation by 90 degrees in the complex plane. In linear algebra, you can represent a 90 degree rotation of a plane by the matrix \begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
How do we resolve that $i$, which is simply just the vector $(0,1)$, is the same as a linear transformation given by a matrix of two vectors?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  As with any linear transformation, the columns of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors; in this case the basis vectors are $1=(1,0)$ and $i=(0,1)$. Multiplication of $1=(1,0)$ by $i$ results in $i=(0,1)$, which is the first column of the matrix, and multiplication of $i=(0,1)$ by $i$ results in $-1=(-1,0)$, which is the second column

Thanks J. W. Tanner for the prompt response. If we do the math in vector form and multiply 1 = (1,0) by i, then the result is (i,0), which is weird. But I suppose the interpretation is that we now have i real parts and 0 imaginary parts, but i real parts is just i, which is (0,1).

That is correct; complex numbers correspond to points in the plane, which correspond to ordered pairs of real numbers, not to ordered pairs of complex numbers

A secondary related question is if we keep the complex numbers in vector format, the notion of scalar multiplication is no longer valid. It is weird because it seems to me that complex numbers can be both scalars and vectors. When operating as a scalar, multiplication makes sense x*yi = xyi. But when operating as vectors, the math no longer makes sense (x,0) * (0,y) = ? How can I reconcile this duality? Are complex numbers really both scalars and vectors?

$\displaystyle r_1e^{i\theta_1} \times r_2e^{i\theta_2} = r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}.~~i = 1 \times e^{i\pi/2}.$

The complex numbers are a $2$-dimensional vector space over the reals.  In this context, the scalars are the real numbers, not the complex numbers

If complex numbers are 2 dimensional vectors, how do you multiply them in vector format. I guess my question is how do you multiply any vector by another vector. I supposed you could do the dot product. But that does not make much sense here because the vectors are orthogonal and the dot product will just be 0. Sorry if this question is dumb, I am just an electrical engineering student taking a DSP course trying to grasp the mysteries of complex numbers.

The product $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(a,0)\cdot(c,0)+(a,0)\cdot(0,d)+(0,b)\cdot(c,0)+(0,b)\cdot(0,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$, but that doesn’t seem your original question

I have never seen this formula anywhere (,)⋅(,)=(−,+). Is this a standard formula taught in linear algebra? Is there a formal name for it so I can google and learn more?

It’s the formula for multiplication of complex numbers expressed as ordered pairs of real numbers

[Summary of my comments]

How do we resolve that [multiplication by] $i$, which is simply just the vector $(0,1)$, is the same as a linear transformation given by a matrix of two vectors?

Complex numbers correspond to points in the plane, which correspond to ordered pairs of real numbers.  The complex numbers are a two-dimensional vector space over the real numbers; in this context, the scalars are the real numbers, not the complex numbers.  A basis for the complex numbers over the real numbers is $1=(1,0)$ and $i=(0,1)$.
As with any linear transformation, the columns of a corresponding matrix are the images of the basis vectors under the transformation.  Multiplication of $1$ by $i$ results in $i=(0,1)$, which is the first column of the matrix, and multiplication of $i$ by $i$ results in $-1=(-1,0)$, which is the second column of the matrix.

Say you have a complex number $z$ where $z=a+bi$ ($a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and $i$ is the imaginary unit).
Multiplying $z$ by $i$ gives us:
$$
zi = (a+bi)i= ai +bi^2
$$
We know $i^2=-1$ and we can simplify to:
$$
zi=ai-b
$$
This demonstrates that multiplying a complex number $z$ by $i$ generates a new complex number. From a geometric standpoint, we know the real part of a complex number is plotted on the x-coordinate with the imaginary part plotted as the y-coordinate (going back to our complex point $z$, we say $a$ is the x value and $b$ is the y value).
When we multiply z by $i$ we are essentially swapping the x and y coordinate and changing the sign of the new x value. When plotted in the complex plane this equals a 90° counterclockwise rotation. If we perform this multiplication of $z$ and $i$ 4 times you will notice we end with the same complex point we started with.

Counterclockwise rotation by an angle $\theta$ in the complex plane is given by
$$
z'=ze^{i\theta}
$$
So if $\theta=\pi/2$, $z'=ze^{i\pi/2}=i\cdot z$. That's all there is to it.
